# Sequence of Retrofits' request where next request depends on result of previous request

Tags: rx-java, rx-android

I have a sequence of Retrofit requests:

```
Observable.interval(0, Integer.MAX_VALUE - 1).concatMap(index -> index == 0 ? getRequestA() : getRequestB()).takeUntil(<condition>)
```

Request B has parameters that it must obtain from result of request A and etc

```
A -> B(p from A.result) -> B1(p from B.result) -> Bn(p from B[n-1].result)
```

How I can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because each *event* will use something from the previous ones, [scan](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/scan.html) is probably the operator you're looking for.

The accumulator will be the combined observable "up to the current event".

Here's a sample implementation:

```
    // Dummy/sample getRequestB
    Func1<Integer, Observable<Integer>> getRequestB = i -> Observable.<Integer>create(sub -> { sub.onNext(2*i+1);sub.onCompleted();});

    Observable.range(0, Integer.MAX_VALUE -1)
            .scan(Observable.just(0), (acc, rangeIdx) -> acc.concatMap(getRequestB::call))
            .concatMap(o -> o)
            .takeUntil(i -> i > 100000)
            .subscribe(System.err::println);
```

Comment: Thanks Gluck. I need some help yet. You said that the accumulator will be the combined observable "up to the current event", but I need that accumulator obtain only previous observable or last item from sequence of observables. Example code: [link](https://github.com/ru-nekit-android/NowAppRx/blob/master/app/src/main/java/ru/nekit/android/nowapprx/LoadEventsService.java).

Comment: Behavior is expected - if watching on log out in the body of accumulation lambda-function - I was getting too many execution of accumulation function and therefore many calls of request B. Example add on the line 47: Log(index) - I got: 0 - on first event, 0 1 - on second event, 0 1 2 - on third event. It is an expected behavior of scan - "apply a function to each item emitted by an Observable, sequentially, and emit each successive value" [rx scan](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/scan.html). I don't need sequentially - I need on previous value from this sequence.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `flatMap`, such as

```
getRequestA().flatMap(a -> getRequestB(a))
             .flatMap(b -> getRequestB1(b))
             .flatMap(b1 -> getRequestB2(b1))
             ...
```

Comment: That's practical only with a finite/known number of chained processes, I added an answer using scan instead as I believe the author was looking for that.